# Exchange Web Services attachments collection is empty

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Has anyone had an issue with EWS (Exchange 2010 SP1) where the email attachments collection is empty?

The email has 5 attachments (some .tif and some .pdf). My code looks something like like:

```
if (email is EmailMessage && email.HasAttachments)
{
    foreach (Attachment attachment in email.Attachments)
    {...
```

[image]

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was something obvious: apparently I need to bind the message before I can access the attachments.

```
  EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, email.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));
```